# can you create a carousel box over a fixed background image? how?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, carousel

I want the homepage of my webpage to have a fixed background image in between the navbar and footer with a smaller carousel box in front of the background image. I've looked around and haven't found anything that looks like this. I kind of don't know where to start. Is it possible?

Comment: of course you can

Comment: You should try to post an example of what you have already done.

Answer (score 0):

The tag that contains your entire main content add a CSS background to it
Below navbar 
Till footer

background:url(link);

Then use your slider as you would normally